# Getting total from query of individual groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I' running a query that returns total count of offices per county.

```
SELECT county, COUNT(county) AS cnt
FROM state
GROUP BY county
ORDER BY county ASC
```

and my results look like this:

```
"Anderson"  "138"
"Andrews"   "17"
"Angelina"  "80"
"Aransas"   "56"
"Archer"    "38"
```

Is there a way to get the total count returned in the same query?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it as a column, use a window function:

```
SELECT county, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as total
FROM state
GROUP BY county
ORDER BY county ASC;
```

If you want it as an additional row, then use [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT county, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM state
GROUP BY county WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: I might have an older version of MySQL running. The first solution throws errors, the second too, unless I move WITH ROLLUP to GROUP BY county and remove ORDER BY...

Comment: Oops, I put the modifier on the `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.43

Comment: If I add a row, how would I use this value?

Comment: @santa . . . I don't understand that comment.  It is on the last row.

Comment: Sorry, I actually need the total count first on an element row and when that one is clicked it will expand and will output the rest rows. I suppose I could hide the l;ast row and move the value with JS

Comment: @santa *I actually need the total count first on an element row* You may (1) Use `CASE WHEN county IS NULL THEN 'Total' ELSE county END AS county` instead of single `county` in output - this will replace NULL with the value `Total`; (2) add `ORDER BY county != 'Total'` - this will put the row with totals to the beginning of the rowset

Comment: Never mind, the second option works great. I rewrote the PHP to output the rows into a var and if the col name is NULL, append to that one. Works great and is pretty fast.